# How to add one general button in TableViewController in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, button

I need add one general or common button to my `TableViewController` like in picture. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Does this button needs to scroll with table view or can always stay visible?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
let bottomButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 100, height: 30))
bottomButton.setTitle("Enter Text Here", for: .normal)
bottomButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
view.addSubview(bottomButton)
```

You can set the x, y positions as per your view controller. Also, set the width and height as per the tableViewController width and height.

Comment: Nice solution @Priya Arora

Answer (score 1):

You have two options if you want a simple solution:

**1. Create a footer view with a button and then add this footer to your table view using methods:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

This solution will make your button scroll with the table view

**2. Use `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`**:

- In storyboard add UITableView to your view controller
- Create an IBOutlet for UITableView - connect it
- Conform your view controller to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`
- set `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self`
- In storyboard add a button bellow table view
- Create IBOutlet for button and connect it

Using this solution, your button will always stay on the screen and only the table view will scroll